# My JavaFX project stops running code at the EventHandler

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

This is some homework I have.  I had it running until I added FX to it.  Now it will pop up a window with the title pane and labels, but the actual function of the code isn't appearing in the window.  The code stops running at the EventHandler and I don't understand why or how to fix it.  It is a text analyzer that counts the word occurrences and displays the word with the count.  If someone can point out where and why the code is wrong and how to fix it, I would appreciate it.

```
package application;
/**
 * <h1>Word Occurrences</h1>
 * The program counts the number of a times words
 * appears in the text.
 * 
 * 
 * @author 
 * @version 3.0
 * @since 4/1/2020
 */

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBase;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Labeled;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.*;


public class TextAnalyzer extends Application {

     /**
     * Override method to produce the output     * 
     * @param s first parameter in the start method 
     * @return Output
     */
    //public TextAnalyzer() {    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage s) {

        // title for the stage
        s.setTitle("Text Analyzer");

        // create a tile pane
        TilePane title = new TilePane();

        // create a label
        Label l = new Label("Word          :          Count");


        // Read in the file
        URLReader obj = new URLReader();

        // run
        EventHandler event = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            private Labeled TextLine;

            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

                // variables
                String inputString = null;

                // Read in the file
                URLReader obj = new URLReader();

                // string from URLReader
                try {
                    inputString = obj.reader();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
                // word array
                String[] wordsArray = inputString.split("\\s+");

                // mapping the array
                Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

                String[] var10 = wordsArray;
                int var9 = wordsArray.length;
            // count words
                //for (String word : wordsArray) {
                for(int var8 = 0; var8 < var9; ++var8) {
                    String word = var10[var8];
                    if (map.containsKey(word)) {
                        int count = map.get(word);
                        map.put(word, count + 1);
                    } else {
                        map.put(word, 1);
                    }
                }

                // output

                Iterator var13 = map.entrySet().iterator();

                while(var13.hasNext()) {
                    Entry<String, Integer> entry = (Entry)var13.next();
                    this.TextLine.setText((String)entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
                }
                /*for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    TextLine.setText(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());


                }*/

            }
        };


        title.getChildren().add(l);

        Scene scene = new Scene(title, 400, 400);

        s.setScene(scene);
        s.show();


    }

/**
 * This is the main method which produces the window and contents
 * from the start method
 * @param args
 */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
        //CreateTable();
    }
}
--------------------------------
package application;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * This is the URL reader to read the URL into a string
 * for processing.
 * 
 * @return FileString
 * @exception IOException on input error 
 * @see IOException
 *
 */

public class URLReader {
    String fileString;

    //public URLReader() {    }

    public String reader() throws MalformedURLException {

        // create the URL
        URL file = new URL("http://shakespeare.mit.edu/macbeth/full.html");

        // Open the URL stream and create readers convert to string
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.openStream()));

            // write the output
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                response.append(inputLine);

            // close reader
            reader.close();         
            fileString = response.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        return fileString.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing a huge amount in that EventHandler. I would suggest printing out each line you're reading to fine out when it stops.

Comment: It never goes through the EventHandler, it seems to stop there.

Comment: How can you tell that it never gets to the EventHandler?

Comment: Debug and nothing is produced after it.

Comment: Its like it ignores the code.\

Comment: Do you ever add the EventHandler (event) to any button or pane?

Comment: As it says, `event handler` handles event but in your case nothing is producing `event`. Bind your `event` for example to `keyPressed` event. 

But in your case I would recommend that you make a button `start` and set the event in `setOnAction` like this:     `startButton.setOnAction((event) -> { //your code comes here });`

Comment: Well that does make sense. Let you know how it works out later.

Comment: unrelated: please stick to java naming conventions - you are nearly always, except _TextLine_ :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, set action to `startButton` that you need to create, and after that set on action like this:

```
startButton.setOnAction((event) -> {
     System.out.println(„Start Button pressed!“);
     // variables
     String inputString = null;

     // Read in the file
     URLReader obj = new URLReader();

     // string from URLReader
     try {
          inputString = obj.reader();
          } catch (MalformedURLException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
      }
      // word array
      String[] wordsArray = inputString.split("\\s+");

      // mapping the array
      Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

      String[] var10 = wordsArray;
      int var9 = wordsArray.length;
      // count words
      //for (String word : wordsArray) {
      for(int var8 = 0; var8 < var9; ++var8) {
         String word = var10[var8];
         if (map.containsKey(word)) {
            int count = map.get(word);
            map.put(word, count + 1);
         } else {
            map.put(word, 1);
         }
       }

       // output

       Iterator var13 = map.entrySet().iterator();

       while(var13.hasNext()) {
           Entry<String, Integer> entry = (Entry)var13.next();
           System.out.println((String)entry.getKey() + " : " + 
           entry.getValue());
       }
       /*for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
         TextLine.setText(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());}*/

});
```

Also, create/define your `Label` private Labeled TextLine; outside the `setOnAction` as you did with `Label l`.

Than, if you want to update the text of the label `TextLine`, update it inside of `setOnAction`

Here is nice article about Java FX Event Handling [link](https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-event-handling-examples/)

Also, I would recommend running your stuff inside `setOnAction` on another thread, not to block your UI. But that is just fine tuning.